# French Chacters becomming corrupted when uploading blobs to Oracle database

Tags: oracle

We have check the NLS_Lang setting on Oracle and they are correct.

The problem we have happening is when we upload a text file as a blob that has french characters the file when it is downloaded again the french characters are all corrupt.

We have one system written in Java another written in Omnis and another in .Net. Now each of these reside on a different server. The .Net app runs from my computer.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: We are uploading files (text files) as data type blob not clobs. So we are actually uploading the txt file into the database. All the french characters when we download the file again appear as a question mark in black background

Comment: If you're using a `blob`, there is no character set conversion so what you get out of Oracle will be bit-for-bit identical to the file you uploaded.  Are you seeing differences in the binary data that is fetched?  What character set are the files in?  Are the two applications running on the same machine?  At some point, if the applications are displaying the documents, they'll have to do some sort of conversion using a particular character set from the binary representation to characters.  I'd guess they aren't doing it the same way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, source “A” produces the text, then it is stored as blob in the db, and then it is consumed by some application “B”. Is the source “A” able to consume (read back) the data, rather than just produce and transmit it? If it can, is there any corruption detectable there? If  there is no corruption when you read back in “A”, you will know that whatever corruption may exist is not caused by the db. More likely, “B” either doesn’t know what it is receiving, or can’t display it.

Comment: So we have a system that creates a file (txt) from data that is input. The file is then uploaded into Oracle as a blob. Once the file has been uploaded, if we now download it all french characters will be corrupt with question marks. wee have 3 apps that do this one is built in Omnis another in Java and one VB. I was looking at the vb app and I am thinking that Filestream doesn't handle UTF and that I should use Streamwriter. I don't know anything about the Java app.

Comment: I am pretty sure it isn't oracle causing this as we also have another table that hold addresses and none of the characters are corrupt. What classes are used in Java to upload blobs? Could they have used the wrong class like one that does not handle UTF?

Comment: This is a sample portion of the test file after it was uploaded and we downloaded it again.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            <Region code="6">
                <English>QU������BEC</English>
                <French>QU������BEC</French>
            </Region>

Comment: When you upload BLOB data then you cannot have any character set issue. Java/JDBC does not use `NLS_LANG` setting. In .NET the `NLS_LNAG` applies only in exceptional cases. You lack a lot of information to get any help.

Comment: How do you up- and download the data?

Comment: Stupid question: Why do you upload/store/download **text** data as `BLOB`?

Comment: Legacy database form 15 years ago+, I asked the exact same question.

Comment: In the Java program I don't know how they do it. In VB I can give you sample code. How do I past code on here?

Comment: _How do I past code on here?_ Have you visited the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not really sure what more information I can post.